# MySQL: How to join data from 2 MySQL tables into 1 single HTML table

Tags: mysql

I have two MySQL tables that are basically in these formats:

**Table 1**

```
id  |  screeningId  |  mainImageUrl  |  movie  |  venue  |  location  |  date

 1          1            red.jpg       Movie1     Venue1    Location1    2015
 2          2            blue.jpg      Movie2     Venue2    Location2    2016
 3          3            orange.jpg    Movie3     Venue3    Location3    2016
 4          4            white.jpg     Movie4     Venue4    Location4    2017
```

**Table 2**

```
id | screeningId | imageUrl
 1        1        red2.jpg
 2        1        red3.jpg
 3        1        red4.jpg
 4        2        red5.jpg
 5        2        red6.jpg
 6        3        red7.jpg
 7        4        blue2.jpg
 8        4        blue3.jpg
....
....
```

I want to print this data into an HTML table, in this format:

```
id |    venue    | imageUrl
 1      venue1     red2.jpg
 2      venue1     red3.jpg
 3      venue1     red4.jpg
 4      venue2     red5.jpg
 5      venue2     red6.jpg
 6      venue3     red7.jpg
 7      venue4     blue2.jpg
 8      venue4     blue3.jpg
....
....
```

For the second table, this is my code for printing this to an HTML table:

```
<table border=1 cellpadding=1 cellspacing=1>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Screening Event</th>
                    <th>Secondary Image</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <?php

                //select query
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM table2";
                if(!$sql){
                    echo"Table not selected";
                }

                //execute the query
                $records = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($records)){
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>".$row['screeningId']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row['imageURL']."</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
            ?>
        </table>
```

This is, of course, just outputting the screeningId and not the matching venue for that screeningId in Table 1. How can I change that out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to write the query as a join, then print out all the rows of the join. The query you want is:

```
select T1.id as id, T1.venue as venue, T2.imageUrl as imageUrl 
from table1 T1 join table2 T2 on T1.screeningId = T2.screeningId;
```

Then you can get the fields from each row to output as HTML with `$row['id']`, `$row['venue']`, and `$row['imageUrl']`.

Comment: What's the difference between `table1` and `T1`? Is `T1` just used in the variable to describe what table the variable is coming from?

Comment: Yep writing `from table1 X` just makes `X` reference that table. It's helpful if two tables have some of the same column names so you can distinguish them, especially so if you join a table with itself.